# In the Trinitarian view does Matthew 11:27 indicate the Holy Spirit does not know the Son?

Tags: trinity, pneumatology

Matthew 11:27
Young's Literal Translation

> 27 `All things were delivered to me by my Father, and none doth know the Son, except the Father, nor doth any know the Father, except the Son, and he to whom the Son may wish to reveal [Him].

**Please Note:  I am quoting a literal translation from the Greek, not the KJV, it does not say "no man", it says "none" as in no one.**

In the above verse, Jesus is apparently saying only the Father knows the Son. How do Trinitarians resolve this with their belief that the Holy Spirit is a person who is not the Father nor the Son, and who is fully God?

Consider this standard diagram of the relationships within the Trinity:
[image]

**Note:**  I am not asking for proof of the concept of Trinity -- I am taking that as a given truth. I am asking given the Trinity is true, is Jesus indicating the Spirit does not know the Son by saying "none know the Son except the Father"

Comment: Jesus said 'I and the Father are one'. So, also, the Father and the Spirit are one. So, also, the Son and the Spirit are one. The Spirit is called 'the Spirit of the Father' and is also called 'the Spirit of Christ'. All of this is very clear in Trinitarian doctrine. It has been clear for 1,700 years. [See Wikipedia - Council of Nicaea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Council_of_Nicaea).

Comment: @NigelJ I am asking a question exploring trinitarianism, I invite you to provide an answer

Comment: I've added a diagram

Comment: I have answered your question in my comment. It was a simple matter and could have been resolved from the documentation on Trinitarian doctrine. // I do not take any notice of diagrams : I study the word of God, personally. // The question does not 'explore' Trintarian doctrine. It actually ignores it. These things are well understood and well publicised in the public domain.

Comment: @NigelJ I thought it was well known that answers do not belong in comments, are you suggesting a way to improve the question or asking for clarification?

Comment: I've added a note indicating I am taking the concept of the trinity as a given truth

Comment: On this and other sites of Stack Exchange it is recognised that some questions can be answered, briefly and succintly, in comment. If that is so, it indicates that the  question might well be tending towards closure.

Comment: @scm intriguingly you seek a Biblical response from a trinitarian source which will not accept the verse you have quoted. Is this outcome the objective?

Comment: @steveowen I'm trying to understand trinitarianism with respect to this particular verse that looked like Jesus implied the Holy Spirit does not know the Son. I've accepted an answer that interprets the verse in a trinitarian way.

Comment: He doesn’t imply it, he states it categorically. As noted in the answers, the verse is dismissed and explained away with doctrine.

Comment: @steveowen do you have the ability to start a chat if you wish a continued discussion?  I don't have the ability to start chats

Comment: No, I don’t wish a discussion on this matter. If you seek Biblical responses to such important matters you will find them addressed in my various posts. If you have related questions, you can comment there. Best wishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clue to your answer is found in the verse you quoted: ". . . and he to whom the Son may wish to reveal [Him]."

The Son of God reveals both himself and the Father to whomever he chooses. That revealing work is done by the Holy Spirit, who is the Son's revealer to those who are being saved. How can the Spirit reveal these things if He knows neither the Son nor the Father?

Furthermore, the apostle Paul gives us more information about the Triune God's revealing of Himself to those who are being saved:

> "What no eye has seen, nor ear heard,
> nor the human heart conceived, what God has prepared for those who love him"
> —God has revealed to us through the Spirit, for the Spirit searches
> everything, even the depths of God" (1 Corinthians 2:9-10).

A natural question to ask in light of Paul's words in 1 Corinthians is: How could the Spirit ***not*** know the Father or the Father know the Spirit if the Spirit searches "everything, even the depths of God"?

There is an organic and mutual self-disclosure within the Godhead. There is nothing the Spirit does not know about the Son and the Father. There is nothing both the Father and the Son do not know about the Spirit. All three are, after all, one. Moreover, each person of the Godhead has a role to play in the grand scheme of redemption which was planned before the foundations of the world were laid (see, for example, Ephesians 1:4, 5, and 11; Acts 2:23; and Revelation 13:8).

Comment: +1 because you addressed the verse in question. I see that where I think Jesus is only referring to knowledge of the Father to those he chooses to reveal, I can see how you apply it to the knowledge of the Son revealed to the Holy Spirit. You're answer is most helpful and I've also marked it accepted

Answer (score 1):

The Holy Spirit proceeds from both God the Father and God the Son. Since this is true, how can the Holy Spirit not know the Son or not the Father for that matter?

Please read John 14;25-26. Normally I would type out the verses but I think it's important that you read them for yourself. Luke 24:49 has Jesus sending the Holy Spirit and at John 15:26 Jesus stated, "He/Holy Spirit will testify about Me."

Yes, the Holy Spirit is a distinct person just like the Father and the Son are distinct persons within the Trinity/Godhead. A person is one that has a personality whose distinctive qualities shows them to be an entity which differs from other beings.

The Holy Spirit has a mind and can think for Itself. Romans 8:27. Acts 15:28. He can dispense gifts to different individuals according as He wills. 1 Corinthians 12:8-11.

The Holy Spirit guides, hears, and shows, John 16:13-15. He sends forth at Acts 13:1-4. The Holy Spirit is the author of the Bible and moved upon the prophets to speak. 2 Peter 1:21. I can give about 25 or so more verses of the Holy Spirit's actions.

Then there is Acts 5:3-4, "But Peter said, "Ananias, why has Satan filled your heart to LIE TO THE HOLY SPIRIT, and keep back some of the price of the land? Vs4, While it remained unsold, did it not remain your own? And after it was sold, was it not under your control? Why is it that you have conceived this deed in your heart? YOU HAVE NOT LIED TO MEN BUT TO GOD."

In closing I give you Romans 8:9-11. "However, you are not in the flesh but in the Spirit, if indeed the Spirit of God dwells in you. But if anyone does not have the Spirit of Christ, he does not belong to Him." Notice the Holy Spirit is interchanged with the Father and the Son.

Vs10, "And if Christ is in you, though the body is dead because of sin, yet the spirit is alive because of righteousness." Vs11, If Jesus Christ is a created being like the rest of us and a man only, how is it that He can make His abode or live in us with His Spirit?

Vs11. "But if the Spirit of Him who raised Jesus from the dead dwells in you, He who raised Christ Jesus from the dead will also give life to your mortal bodies through His Spirit who indwells you."

Comment: how be it that Jesus says only the Father knows the Son? Can you add that to your answer?

Comment: The answer is right before your eyes. You quoted Matthew 11:27, why didn't you read it in its entirety? The verse clearly states that only the Father knows the Son. Then you stopped at the part where Jesus says He knows the Father.  The Father does not have a separate manifestation from the Son. The only manifestation and revelation of the Father is the Son. John 14:9.  What is known of the Father is revealed through the Son. This is because Philippians 2:6 says the Son already existed in the form of God and at vs7 Jesus took the form of a bond-servant/man. God became a man, John 1:14.

Comment: As my question asks, Does the Spirit know the Son, given Jesus said none know the Son but the Father?

Comment: @scm  Your not thinking straight by not using common sense. You cannot go around and take the words of verses and "isolate" them without including the context of the verse. Yes, at Matthew 11:27 Jesus did say in His own words, "none knows the Son but the Father." What's the second part of the verse? Jesus says, "no man knows the Father except the Son." Here's my question? Do you scm know God the Father? I'll answer for you. No, you do not know the Father, in fact you don't know the Son. To know the Son is to know the Father. John 14:6, No one comes to the Father except through Me. Trust Jesus.

Comment: I'll add a note that I quoted a literal translation from the Greek.  It does not say "no man" it says "none"

Comment: @scm Read your quote again. "All things were delivered to me by my Father, and none doth know the Son, except the Father, nor doth any know the Father, except the Son, and he to whom the Son may wish to reveal [Him]." Yes, it does say "none" doth/does not know the Father except the Son." Then it says, "nor," which means something is not true of both. In other words, no one or anyone does not know the Father just as "no one" or anyone or none knows the Son. This is basic grammar scm. Take time to look up words in Strong's Lexicon and apply it to the context of how it is used in various verses.

Answer (score 1):

There is (according to standard, traditional Catholic theology) a single divine Intellect, common to all three Persons of the Trinity. In particular, the Holy Spirit knows the Son just as the Father knows the Son (and just as the Son knows Himself).

Comment: can you update your answer to address the question? Jesus said effectively none but the Father knows the Son, I am asking how this verse is resolved in Trinitarianism -- where I believe there is an assumption that the Spirit knows the Son.

Comment: @scm You just said, "I believe there is an assumption that the Spirit knows the Son." No, it's not an assumption, it's a fact that the Holy Spirit knows the Son. Read John 14:26. John 15:26-27. John 16:12-13. The Holy Spirit glorifies Jesus Christ at John 16:14-15. All of your "arguments/objections" have been addressed. Please explain to me what I'm missing?

Comment: Your answer did not refer to the verse in question. See the answer I accepted

Comment: @scm this is what you are up against - *it's a fact that the Holy Spirit knows the Son*, says Mr. Bond, even though the Bible says the *exact* opposite. But that doesn't matter here on C-SE as doctrine rules!

Comment: @steveowen i’ve begun looking at your posts and have a glimer of where you are coming from, and i actually need recovery time over the grief i have received asking this one question

Comment: @scm :( you'll get over it. There are some issues with these sites but the 'iron sharpening iron' is good value Ps 27:17. Great to better understand the Bible when you encounter the various views and expertise here which must be discerned wisely and compared to what the Bible *actually* says not what we are *told* it says. Best wishes.